# Detect real changes in input number jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, onchange

I have a form where I have a plus an minus button to change an input number. If the number reaches the max it won't let to add any more to it. But the issue is that is still fires the change event, despite the fact it technically haven't been changed. What can I do in that case?

JQUERY:

```js
var countdown;
jQuery(document).on('change', ".qty", function() {
  var quantity = jQuery(this).val();
  var maxquantity = jQuery(this).attr("max");
  clearTimeout(countdown);
  if (quantity == 0) {
    if (confirm("really?")) {
      // Running without a noticeable delay since the user confirmed their choice.
      countdown = setTimeout(wauc_update_cart, 100);
    }
  } else if (quantity == maxquantity) {
    console.log("max");
  } else {
    countdown = setTimeout(wauc_update_cart, 1000);
  }

});

function wauc_update_cart() {
  jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
  console.log("meghivva");
}

//I CAN NOT EDIT THIS PART!

jQuery('.plus.button').on('click', function() {

  var count = parseInt(jQuery('.qty').val());
  var maxquantity = jQuery('.qty').attr("max");
  var ujszam = 0;

  if (count == maxquantity) {
    var ujszam = maxquantity;
  } else {
    var ujszam = count + 1;
  }

  jQuery('.qty').val(ujszam).change();

});

jQuery('.minus.button').on('click', function() {

  var count = parseInt(jQuery('.qty').val());
  var ujszam = 0;

  if (count == 0) {
    var ujszam = 0;
  } else {
    var ujszam = count - 1;
  }

  jQuery('.qty').val(ujszam).change();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_635fccb23107f">Test item 1</label>
  <input type="button" value="﹣" class="minus button is-form">
  <input type="number" id="quantity_635fccb23107f" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="7" oldvalue="6" name="cart[ab21e63bd2a052ce9fe5dab95a189b62][qty]" value="5" title="Mny" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" oldvalue="14">
  <input type="button" value="﹢" class="plus button is-form">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you modify the HTML?

Comment: Save the previous value in a global variable or `data-val` attribute. Then compare the new value with the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you don't want to clear the countdown timeout after reaching the max (7 in this case) and clicking the plus button, right?

If you want to prevent this, you can add a new attribute to your count element, where you save the old value. Then in the change function, you check the current value with the old value and execute the countdown only if the values are different.

```
var countdown;
jQuery(document).on('change', ".qty", function (e) {
    var quantity = jQuery(this).val();
    var oldValue = jQuery(this).attr("old-value");
    if (oldValue !== quantity) {
    jQuery(this).attr("old-value", quantity);
        var maxquantity = jQuery(this).attr("max");
        clearTimeout(countdown);
        if (quantity == 0) {
            if (confirm("really?")) {
                // Running without a noticeable delay since the user confirmed their choice.
                countdown = setTimeout(wauc_update_cart, 100);
            }
        }
        else {
            countdown = setTimeout(wauc_update_cart, 1000);
        }

    }

});

function wauc_update_cart() {
    jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
    console.log("meghivva");
}
```

Comment: The increment is coming from the `click` handlers on the buttons, not the `change` handler. It's not a default action, it's due to `jQuery('.qty').val(ujszam).change();`

Comment: Hey @Barmar, yes, but I thought the problem is the execution of the `wauc_update_cart` method. If you increase the value from 5 to 7 in less than 1000ms, the method will not be executed. If you increase to 6, wait for a second, and then increase to 7 it's executed once. But that's also why I asked at the end for more information, about what he really expects from the code.

Comment: Hi @MarcelFrank! You got it right, all I want to do is if the maximum is reached to stop the countdown, actually to run it once and then does not matter how many times the user clicks on the plus not to let the countdown to run.

Comment: Hey @Simulator88, I updated my answer. Now it should fit your needs.